# Is there a way to extract specific character strings, multiple times, with grep / sed. Starts with an "("

Tags: xml, sed, terminal, grep

I am trying to extract all the station codes of a txt file. I converted this file from xml to .txt

Here is an example of the text I am trying to extract from.

```
<tr bgcolor="#F2F9FF"><td headers="Station Name"><a href="display.php?stid=KMLJ">Milledgeville, Baldwin County Airport</a> (KMLJ)</td>
<td headers="rss"><div align="center"><a href="KMLJ.rss"><img src="/images/rss.jpg" alt="RSS Format" width="36" height="14" border="0"></a></div></td>
<td headers="xml"><div align="center"><a href="KMLJ.xml"><img src="/images/xml.gif" alt="XML Format" width="36" height="14" border="0"></a></div></td>
</tr>
<tr><td headers="Station Name"><a href="display.php?stid=K2J5">Millen Airport</a> (K2J5)</td>
<td headers="rss"><div align="center"><a href="K2J5.rss"><img src="/images/rss.jpg" alt="RSS Format" width="36" height="14" border="0"></a></div></td>
<td headers="xml"><div align="center"><a href="K2J5.xml"><img src="/images/xml.gif" alt="XML Format" width="36" height="14" border="0"></a></div></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F2F9FF"><td headers="Station Name"><a href="display.php?stid=KD73">Monroe-Walton County Airport</a> (KD73)</td>
<td headers="rss"><div align="center"><a href="KD73.rss"><img src="/images/rss.jpg" alt="RSS Format" width="36" height="14" border="0"></a></div></td>
<td headers="xml"><div align="center"><a href="KD73.xml"><img src="/images/xml.gif" alt="XML Format" width="36" height="14" border="0"></a></div></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried grep and sed.

```
 sed -n '(k' stations.txt
```

I want to export either to a csv or a textfile with just the desired string, i.e. (KMLJ) (K2J5) (KD73)

Comment: Do you mean `sed -n '/^(k/p' stations.txt` / `grep '^(k' stations.txt`?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. @WiktorStribiżew I added the example .txt file.

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `grep -io '(k[^()]*)' stations.txt`? BTW, you posted a HTML, not plain text, file

Comment: @Cyrus added desired output. Let me know if the formatting needs changing. New to stackoverflow

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew changed. Also you're solution worked! Thank you for the help

Comment: This is madness. When searching XML, you want to take advantage of the structure inherent in the tags. Getting rid of the structure first, and then searching, can't possibly be the right approach.

Comment: @MichaelKay what would you use to read it?

Comment: I would use XSLT or XQuery. But any XML-aware tool would be fine, whatever you are most comfortable with, so long as it has a proper XML parser underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -o '([Kk][^()]*)' stations.txt
```

Or, to get the values without parentheses:

```
grep -Po '\(\K[Kk][^()]+' stations.txt # GNU grep required
# Or, just pipe a sed to remove the initial (:
grep -o '([Kk][^()]*' stations.txt | sed 's/^(//'
```

Or, with `sed` only, if there is a single value per line:

```
sed -n 's/.*(\([kK][^()]*\).*/\1/p'  stations.txt
```

The `-o` option will output matched texts only.

The `([Kk][^()]*)` is a POSIX BRE pattern here that matches:

- `(` - a literal `(` char
- `[Kk]` - a bracket expression matching `k` or `K`
- `[^()]*` - a negated bracket expression matching any char but `(` and `)` zero or more times
- `)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you know of a simple way to remove the parentheses. Currently trying to find solutions.

Comment: @noxford1 I added 2 solutions: one is purely `grep` based but requres a GNU grep, and the second is with `sed` piped to the grep results. And just added a third solution based on `sed` only.

Comment: The second one is exactly what I was looking forward. Thank you for the solution and explanation, helped me better understand grep!

Comment: @noxford1 Sorry, there was a bug in the `-Po` version, the first `(` must be escaped in the PCRE regex to match a literal `(`: `grep -Po '\(\K[Kk][^()]+'`

Comment: More complex question. Lets say I want to take that output, which I stored in a .txt file named stationList.txt,  and CP files from a folder with names that match strings in the .txt file. The file's I am trying to cp, or merge, are .xml. 

https://i.imgur.com/aHiCn31.png

Comment: @noxford1 That sounds like a new question to me.

Comment: Thank you for all your help again. I will create my new question soon. Still learning how this communities works.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that?

```
sed -n '/Station Name/ {s/.*stid=\([^"]*\)">\([^<]*\)<.*/\1 \2/;p}' file.txt
```

**explanation**

```
sed -n            # use sed with no default output
'/Station Name/   # use onle lines with Station Name
{                 # start block
s                 # substitute
/                 # separator
.*stid=\([^"]*\)  # extract Station ID and save it in arg1 (\1)
">                # ignore this pattern
\([^<]*\)         # extract Station Name and save it in arg2 (\2)
<.*               # ignore rest of line
/\1 \2/;p         # print arg1 and arg2
}                 # end of block
' file.txt        # read from this file
```

**output of your testdata**

```
KMLJ Milledgeville, Baldwin County Airport
K2J5 Millen Airport
KD73 Monroe-Walton County Airport
```

Comment: When I ran this command I received this response.

sed: 1: "/Station Name/ {s/.*sti ...": extra characters at the end of p command
noxford-NHJGH6:~ noxford$